How can I get the updations that are made in any of the object in the salesforce in real time?
I need to get the all the updations that are made in any of the object in the salesforce account in realtime. I tried many ways like Outbound message, CDC, stream api but its not resolve my issue. I have around 60+ custom tables, for creating multiple flows or CDC for each object is hectic and it have there own limitations. like CDC can have max 5 objects at a time. So any one please get me some guidance to resolve this issue.
I tried all the possibilities in the salesforce like CDC, Outbound msg, streaming api all have only single objects at a time
